# I want to fill a database with 4,000,000 entries, every possible result of two numbers?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out a way to enter 4,000,000 values of possible combinations of 1 - 2000.

One column (I'll call it the x-coord) to make it easier and the y-coord, I want both to include every number from 1 to 2000, but I also want x to be 1 for 2000 entries where y is 1 - 2000.

An example of the script I was trying to write to do it would be:

*(I've simplified the PDO part since that is irrelevant)*

```
   while ($insertcount < 1501) {
    insert $insertcount into x-coord.
    insert $ydata into y-coord.

    $insertcount++;
            if ($insertcount >= 1501) {
                if ($ydata < 1500) {
                $ydata++;
                $insertcount = 1001;
                }
            }
    }
```

I had to break the number I was putting in at once because the script/mysql would timeout the connection.

Any ideas for the most efficient way of doing this? Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you write out a CSV with all the data you want to load, then use `LOAD DATA INFILE`?

Comment: Using parameterized queries would offer some benefit, while putting multiple inserts in one large query would offer even larger benefit. Also, if indexed, insert in index order (primary key if InnoDB).

Comment: That sounds straight forward enough. Do you have any tips for creating that CSV quickly? Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Using PL/SQL could dramatically increase the speed of batch inserts.